# google gsutil: ascii codec can't encode character

Tags: python, character-encoding, gsutil

I'm trying to sync my local folder on google cloud nearline storage, but I get the following error:

```
"Caught non-retryable exception while listing file:///var/lib/..: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 170: ordinal not in range(128)
CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync
Caught ^C - exiting"
```

Is there any solution please?
Thank you.

Comment: Change the names of your folders in A-Za-z0-9 and  some  special characters only also avoid using very large names for folders, as this may increase length of the path string resulting in the error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer anmol_uppal, but I tried to sync also a file in an  "A-Za-z0-9" folder name, but the error persist. I guess it regards the character encoding different from UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an accented e - é located in a filename that you are attempting to sync.

Using UTF-8 for all object names and filenames will ensure that gsutil doesn’t encounter character encoding errors while operating on the files. Unfortunately, it’s still possible that files uploaded / downloaded this way can have interoperability problems, for a number of reasons unrelated to gsutil; example: copying filenames across different platforms like Linux and Windows. If you are using the Windows console you can specify wildcards or folders (using the -R option) rather than explicitly named individual files in order to prevent this.

If you have too many files you can use a tool to convert the old character encoding to UTF-8. One such tool is [native2ascii](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/native2ascii.html).

Comment: as there are thousands of files, how to find which file name is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use https://github.com/minio/mc which supports Google Cloud Storage in S3 compatibility mode.

`mc` is fully UTF-8 , can upload and download with all known UTF-8 characters.

Get your AccessKeyID and SecretAccessKey by following Google Credentials Guide. Once you have them update your ~/./mc/config.json configuration file.

```
$ mc config host add storage.googleapis.com <your_access_key> <your_secret_key> S3v2
```

NOTE: Google Cloud Storage only supports Legacy Signature Version 2 :(, so you have to pick - S3v2